# Spring Data: JPA and Nested Transaction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem with Spring JPA Data and nested transactions. Following are two methods with a nested transaction of my service.

```
@Service
public UserService {

    @Transactional
    public User createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        ....
        user = saveUser(user);
        sendEmail(user);
        ....
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

It happens there is one scenario that the method userRepository.save() should throw an exception but somehow is not being thrown, it looks like it is waiting the parent transaction to be finished. I was expecting the exception being thrown on the saveUser method and the sendEmail method not even to be executed.

Because the method `UserService.saveUser` have the propagation set to `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` I was expecting that transaction to be commited (the SQL statement to be executed) and any exception being propagated.

I did not setup anything related with Transaction, so i believe that the flush mode is set to AUTO.

Can anyone spot what i am doing wrong or what is my misconception?

Comment: Why do you think that userRepository.save() should throw and exception? And if it is throw the saveUser transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: In my specific scenario because some constraints fails. So I was expecting an exception to be thrown immediately and sendEmail not even called. In yet the saveUser exception is only thrown when createUser finish. The below approach fixes the issue. Thank you very much Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're invoking `@Transactional` method from within same bean.

`@Transactional` only works on methods invoked on proxies created by spring. It means, that when you create a @Service or other bean, method called from the outside will be transactional. If invoked from within bean, nothing will happen, as it doesn't pass through proxy object.

The easiest solution would be to move the method to another @Service or bean. If you really want to keep it within same component, then you need to invoke it, so that it gets wrapped in proxy by spring AOP. You can do this like that:

```
private YourClass self;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@PostConstruct
public void postContruct(){
    self = applicationContext.getBean(YourClass.class);
}
```

Then invoking method on `self` would result in opening a transaction.

In other words: **you are not experiencing any of those anomalies, because `@Transactional` over `saveUser` does not work.**

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem, glad to help:)